# Strengthened form of weak convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-probability, weak-convergence

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ be a subalgebra, $X$ be a real-valued random variable and $X_1,X_2,..$ be $\mathcal{G}$-measurable random variables s.t.
$$
\mathbb{E}[Uf(X_n)] \rightarrow \mathbb{E}[Uf(X)]
$$
holds for all continuous bounded $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{G}$-measurable bounded $U:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Does this imply
$$
\mathbb{E}[Uf(X_n)] \rightarrow \mathbb{E}[Uf(X)]
$$
for all continuous bounded $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{F}$-measurable bounded $U:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

It would be very useful for me if this holds, but I can find neither a proof nor a counter example. I would be greatful for a help.

Answer (score 4):

The statement is true iff $X$ is also  $\mathcal G- $  measurable (w.r.t to its completion to be more precise).

Suppose  $X$ is $\mathcal G- $ measurable. $E[Uf(X_n)]=E[E[Uf(X_n)|\mathcal G]]=E[f(X_n)E[U|\mathcal G]]=E[Vf(X_n)]$ where $V=E[U|\mathcal G]$ is $\mathcal G-$ measurable. Similarly, $E[Uf(X)]=E[Vf(X)]$.  Just apply the hypothesis now.

Without loss of generality we may suppose $f(x)=x$ for all $x$. If the conclusion holds for  a general $X$ then we have $E[UX]=E[VX]$. But $EVX=E[E[(VX)|\mathcal G]]=E[VE[X|\mathcal G]]=E[UE[X|\mathcal G]]$. Now $E[UX]=E[UE[X|\mathcal G]]$. The validity of this equation for all $\mathcal F-$ measurable $U$ implies that $X=E[X|\mathcal G]$ a.e., so $X$ is necessarily measurable w.r.t. (the completion of) $\mathcal G$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but why should $E[Uf(X)]=E[Vf(X)]$ be true? Note that X is not $\mathcal{G}$-measurable.

Comment: @Learner I missed that fact. I have updated my answer. I think your conclusion is true if and only if $X$ is  $\mathcal G- $ measurable.

Comment: @Learner I have added a detailed proof of the fact that $\mathcal G$ measurability of $X$ is necessary for the conclusion to hold.

Comment: I think you must replace $X$ by $f(X)$ and then you get $f(X)=E[f(X)|\mathcal G]$ almost surely for all $f \in C_b(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$. Does that imply $X=E[X|\mathcal G]$ a.e.?

Comment: $f$ plays no role at all in the question. @l

Comment: "If the conclusion holds for  a general $X$ then we have $E[UX]=E[VX]$." Why should this be true?

Comment: Yes, if $f(X)$ is measurable for each $f$ then $X$ is. You just have to note that the identity function is a pointwise limit of bounded continuous functions.

Comment: Since $V $ is $\mathcal G-$V measurable we already know that $EUX_n=EVX_n \to EVX$.  We wanrt this to be equal to $EUX$ so we must have $EUX=EVX$ if  the conclusion has to hold.  @Learner